# Where is java's system preference stored under mac? Couldn't find it

Tags: java, file, storage, system, preference

I've got following code snippet:

```
public void setPreference() throws Exception {
    prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node(this.getClass().getName());
    String ID1 = "Test1";
    String ID2 = "Test2";
    String ID3 = "Test3";

    System.out.println(prefs.getBoolean(ID1, true));
    System.out.println(prefs.get(ID2, "Hello World"));
    System.out.println(prefs.getInt(ID3, 50));

    prefs.putBoolean(ID1, false);
    prefs.put(ID2, "Hello Europa");
    prefs.putInt(ID3, 45);
    prefs.remove(ID1);
    prefs.flush();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    PreferenceTest test = new PreferenceTest();
    test.setPreference();
}
```

Yes, it runs well, restore system preference before I set them. I google-ed and it said that on mac, the preference is stored under $HOME as an hiden file. But I "ls -al ~" but didn't find a new hidden file. So what's its name and what's the content of it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Look inside `$JAVA_HOME`

Comment: Didn't see any new hidden file. Could I know the preference file name please? It is a fixed file name? thanks.